# Vectors on a plane

Tags: vectors, 3d, plane-geometry

I am stuck on a question that involves vectors in a plane.

> Show that the planes $ax+az=c$ and $bx-by=d$, where $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}, a,b \ne 0$, always form an angle of $\pi/3 = 60^\circ$.

The link to solution to this problem is here (I do not understand it): https://asxtronomical.tumblr.com/post/626215701033664512
I would appreciate it if someone can explain to me step-by-step how to get to the solution.

Comment: Never post unsearchable images.  Instead always typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: Hint: if $\mathcal{P},\mathcal{Q}$ are two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with normal vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}$, is there a relationship between the angle of the planes and the angle of their normal vectors?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Which part of the solution don't you understand?  finding the normal vectors? finding $\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between them?  finding $\theta$ such that $\cos\theta=\frac12$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea would be to note that the angle between planes is the same as the angle between their normal vectors, which are $(a,0,a)$ and $(b,-b,0)$.

Now for any vectors $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$, the key to the angle $\theta_{xy}$ between them is in their dot product, which can be computed coordinate-wise, but is also given by
$$
\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} = \left|\vec{x}\right| \left|\vec{y}\right| \cos\theta_{xy}.
$$
You have $\vec{x} = (a,0,a), \vec{y} = (b,-b,0)$. Can you find $\theta_{xy}$?